# On sub-maximally symmetric Riemannian spaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry, isometry-groups

Is there a 4-dimensional Riemannian manifold with 8-dimensional isometry group?

**Context:** Guido Fubini (Annali di Mat., ser. 3, 8 (1903) 54) shows that the dimension $n$ of the isometry group of a $d$-dimensional, sub-maximally symmetric Riemannian space is bounded by $n \le d(d+1)/2-1$ for $d\ge 3$. For $d=3$, Fubini's bound is optimal, saturated for example by the Berger-sphere. The above question amounts to asking if Fubini's bound is optimal for $d=4$.

Fubini's theorem is generalized to the *pseudo*-Riemannian setting by G. S. Hall (Class. Quantum Grav. 20 (2003) 3745).

V. Patrangenaru (Geometriae Dedicata 102 (2003) 25) shows that Fubini's generalized bound is optimal for $d=1+3$, $1+5$, $1+6$,...

Comment: $\mathbb{CP}^2$ endowed with the Fubini-Study metric has dimension $4 $ and has an $8$-dimensional isometry group (the identity component is $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ modulo its center, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$).  It's also symmetric.